# How to create a custom HTML element with Ace Editor?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, ace-editor, custom-element

I am trying to create a custom HTML element using Web Components that will contain an instance of Ace Editor. My attempted solution is the following

```
 customElements.define("test-editor", class  extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
           super();

           const editorContainer = document.createElement("div");
           editorContainer.setAttribute("id", "editor_container");

           const root = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
           root.appendChild(editorContainer);
      }

      connectedCallback() {
           ace.edit("editor_container");
      }
 });
```

I then try to use this custom element in the following HTML (custom_element.js contains the above)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <style>
           html, body, #editor_container {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
           }
      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
      <test-editor></test-editor>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js"></script>
      <script src="custom_element.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I load this page in either Chrome or Firefox, I get the following error in the console

> Uncaught Error: ace.edit can't find div #editor_container
> at Object.t.edit (ace.js:1)
> at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (custom_element.js:17)
> at custom_element.js:3

Is there any way I can embed an instance of Ace Editor in a custom element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a demo](https://raw.githack.com/ajaxorg/ace/master/demo/shadow-dom.html) of using shadow-dom in ace repository

The important part is to pass dom element instead of a string to the edit method
And to call [editor.renderer.attachToShadowRoot](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/afa8f35997cd056b31c4d5be1c3daa316b17b5ac/demo/shadow-dom.html#L99)

Answer (score 2):

You have attached a shadowDOM to your Component.

Because the ACE Editor code is loaded in the page DOM (green),
it can only find ACE containers in the page DOM (green).

[image]

Note: You also had the `<style>` in pageDOM. That will never style elements **in** shadowDOM.
The whole essence of shadowDOM is **encapsulation**

See: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom

#### You have 2 options to make the ACE editor work in a Custom Element:

- Use shadowDOM, does need a lot of scripting. But you can get multiple editors in one page. See: https://raw.githack.com/ajaxorg/ace/master/demo/shadow-dom.html
- **not** use shadowDOM
  (and while we are at it, let the Element load all dependencies):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <script id=myEditor>
       customElements.define("my-editor", class extends HTMLElement {
         connectedCallback() {
           const script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
           script.src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js";
           script.onload = () => {
             this.innerHTML = `<div id=editor_container>${myEditor.innerHTML}</div>`;
             ace.edit("editor_container", {
               mode: "ace/mode/javascript",
               theme: "ace/theme/cobalt"
             });
           }
           document.head.append(script);
         }
       });
     </script>
     <style>
       html,
       body,
       #editor_container {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
       }
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <my-editor></my-editor>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Or checkout more config examples at:
https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/jznf45sg/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the simplest way to add an editor to a web component the Ace team does provide an api, just build an editor and then add it to the shadow dom like this:

```
aceEditor.renderer.attachToShadowRoot();
```

Here is one I built to display a snippet of code from a file (it displays the file name as well as the code):

```
class CodeSnippet extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(fileName, fileContents) {
    super();

    this._fileName = fileName;
    this._fileContents = fileContents;

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.getTemplate());
  }

  getTemplate() {
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = `
<style>
  .fileName {
    color: gray;
  }
</style>
<div class="fileName"></div>
<div class="codeSnippet"></div>`;
    return template.content.cloneNode(true);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    //display the file name
    const fileName = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.fileName');
    fileName.innerHTML = this._fileName;

    //used to set the height of the ace editor (always have at least one line)
    let numNewLines = 1;
    //collect the newlines (null if there are none)
    const allNewLines = this._fileContents.match(/\n/g);
    if(allNewLines) {
      //add an extra for the last line without a newline on it
      numNewLines = allNewLines.length + 1;
    } 

    //get the element where you want to add the editor
    const codeSnippet = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.codeSnippet');
    //build an ace editor like normal
    const aceEditor = ace.edit(codeSnippet, {
        theme: "ace/theme/monokai",
        mode: "ace/mode/java",
        value: this._fileContents, //code to display
        showPrintMargin: false,
        readOnly: true,
        fontSize: 16,
        maxLines: numNewLines, //auto set the height of the editor
        highlightActiveLine: false,
        highlightGutterLine: false
    });

    //attach the ace editor to the shadow dom
    aceEditor.renderer.attachToShadowRoot();
  } 
}

window.customElements.define('code-snippet', CodeSnippet);
```

Don't forget that you need access to the Ace library somewhere in your code. I use a CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

To test it you can add them to another component:

```
const codeView = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.codeView');
const snippet1 = new CodeSnippet('/testFile1.txt', 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3');
codeView.appendChild(snippet1);

const snippet2 = new CodeSnippet('/testFile2.txt', 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n');
codeView.appendChild(snippet2);

const snippet3 = new CodeSnippet('/testFile3.txt', '');
codeView.appendChild(snippet3);
```

[image]